# django: how to load the static files with hash/md5 appending correctly?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

**using Django 3**

I followed the Django Doc
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage
to export my static files with a hash appending.

---

> **settings.py** production

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

---

> static_root folder (output)

```
 static_root/
          staticfiles.json
 static_root/css/
               project_styles.87c2920e7bc3.css
               project_styles.css
```

everything is collected correctly.

---

Afterwards i uploaded everything to my apache static server.
And i set off / comment  the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` . That is how i understand the Doc´s? If i leave this setting on in production i get an `500 Error`.

> **settings.py** production

```
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

After restarting my Django app in production, my site is still loading `project_styles.css` but not the hash Version  `project_styles.87c2920e7bc3.css` in my browser. Even if i delete `project_styles.css` Django will not serve the hash version.

### Question

---

Did i miss some settings in the `settings.py` in production mode?
In the Doc´s they mention to set `STATICFILES_STORAGE = django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage` but it shows no difference. And as it is mentioned it´s only for testing.

What i have to do to load the correct static hash version in production? do i have to set something in my templates, so that django will look into the json file for the correct hash version? Or do i have to name the hash file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the Problem was that i wanted two different STATIC_ROOT Paths. One for Development and one for Production, because i want all my Development stuff in one Project folder. Because if you `collectstatic` with the STATIC_ROOT of your apache server, django will export it for instance into `c:/var/www/your/server/static` while i wanted it to  `c:/webprojects/myproject_1/static_root_exports` and later upload these files on my server separately.

So i set two different Path depending on `DEV_STATIC` off / on in my django-environ file. Django will set the correct Path.

> .env

```
DEBUG=off
# --- applies media server & sets MEDIA_ROOT & STATIC_ROOT
DEV_STATIC=on

<...>

STATIC_ROOT_DEV=static_root_exports
STATIC_ROOT_PROD=/var/www/myUserName/html/myproject_assets/static

<...>
```

> setting.py

```
# -- Set for Hash
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# --- STATIC_ROOT
if DEV_STATIC == True:
    STATIC_ROOT = SERVER_DIR.joinpath(env('STATIC_ROOT_DEV'))
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = env('STATIC_ROOT_PROD')
```

Comment: Just a little observation but you should have different .env files for prod and dev so you don't have to be writing `if` for every setting in settings.py. You will simply have `STATIC_ROOT` in each env file and load it in settings without any `if`